# PAYUM: Custom Gateway Method

Tags: symfony, sylius, payum

I use an existing symfony project with sylius bundle and included payum bundle.
I have already some bundle in the src folder.

I need to create a custom gateway.
For this I found that : https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Core/Resources/docs/develop-gateway-with-payum.md

But, *what about **where** to execute the command line "composer create-project payum/skeleton", it seems to be important to apply new skeleton into current project ?*

And then in the documentation, there are these informations :

- Replace all occurrences of payum with your vendor name. It may be your github name, for now let's say you choose: acme
- Replace all occurrences of skeleton with a payment gateway name. For example Stripe, Paypal etc. For now let's say you choose: paypal.

*What does that mean ? replace all folder name, all file name, all terms in files ?*

And finally, this documentation talks about : "Register a gateway factory to the payum's builder and create a gateway"

*Where to do that ? How to do that ? Is there a command line or something like that ?*

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the [Sylius documentation about custom gateway configuration](http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/paypal.html). It should really help you with it.
2. Payum documentation just emphasize how to setup project. [Here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) you have a little bigger explanation of command and step 2 and 3. If you have existing project you can skip this part. Only the last point should interest you.

Comment: Sylius and Payum documentations seem to be deprecated about a lot of implementation. First I tried to use it as explained in documentations, but it never works if we follow them. Therefore I used stackoverflow to get some informations. Anyway, I succeed in configuring payum and develop a custom gateway, and now I am looking for documentation about how to deal with status through StatusAction and CaptureAction, and also I want to use some other action but never they are triggered via the payum core... and of course there is not an explicit official documentation ^^

Comment: Issue is solved. Skeleton is good way to build a custom gateway, I checked a lot how other gateways behave, some are very good for inspiration. First issues when we use payum are about how actions are ran, and how they work together. To check any action, some exchanges are hidden, use notify method like mail to debug (dump or print are not usefull when action is played from bank to your application). Then you know how and when any action is ran. Documentation is well built, each project is different and requires some specific research. Thanks a lot to sylius community !